# How to autoprint Itext PDF to default printer?

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, itext

Is there any way to auto print a finished PDF from Itext? Right now it comes up in my web browser then I have to hit print, select a printer and hit print again.  Any way to once it's created to print?  Here are my last 4 lines of Itext

```
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
Response.End();
```

Comment: This used to be possible many years ago, but it was considered an undesired security hazard. Imagine SPAMmers putting PDF's online that start printing themselves automatically whether you like that or not. To avoid this, the functionality was removed from all PDF viewers. The only thing you can do, is opening the print dialog in an *open action*, but even that won't work with all viewers.

Comment: If `writer` is your `PdfWriter` instance, you can do this: `PdfAction action = new PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG);
writer.SetOpenAction(action);` As explained in the previous comment, some viewers will ignore this, and you'll still have to manually click a button in the print dialog anyway

Comment: Ahh... that makes sense.  So really they will need go through the print processes.  I tried that PRINTDIALOG and nothing happened in Firefox.

Comment: Firefox uses pdf.js as PDF viewer. That's... a poor PDF viewer. Try replacing it with the Adobe Reader plug-in if that's still possible. Adding a header that changes the `Content-Disposition` to `attachment` instead of `inline` could do the trick. Google those words for more info.